# soap php json request information array

Tags: php, soap

I am having some issues trying to get the information I need from a soap request. Can you guys help me out?

I need to send this

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://ips.iplabs.de/types">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <typ:soImportItem>
        <TImportItem_1>
            <sessionID>10101010</sessionID>
            <wipeVersion>?</wipeVersion>
            <serviceItemId>bbba051</serviceItemId>
            <itemId>A4647</itemId>
        </TImportItem_1>
    </typ:soImportItem>
</x:Body>
```

To an url. I cant really find information how to do this.
I tried this

```
$tImportItem = array(
'sessionID' => '10101010',
'wipeVersion' => '1.2',
'serviceItemId' => '101010',
'itemId' => 'A4458'
);


$client = new SoapClient('URL/wipe/service?WSDL');


try{
  $response = $client->soImportItem($tImportItem);

  print_r($response);
}catch(SoapFault $SoapFault){
  echo $SoapFault->getMessage();
}
```

Running this code it gives me an 'Fault occurred while processing.' Error.

Answer (score 0):

You're certainly not sending the data as expected, that's all.

If you don't know how to structure the data, then use a WSDL to php generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project. Then you won't wonder how to structure the data to send as soon as you use an adapted IDE such as phpStorm or Eclipse PDT.